# Buscar registro en una tabla del mismo nombre en varias bdd y obtener el nombre de la bdd que tiene el registro

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando buscar un registro en una tabla del mismo nombre en varias bdd y obtener el nombre de la bdd que tiene el registro.

Por ejemplo: la tabla "Persona" está en la bdd sucursal1, en la bdd sucursal2, ... y en la bdd sucursal30. El registro que busco es en el campo "Identificacion" de la tabla "persona" que se encuentra en 30 bases de datos diferentes. Cómo obtengo el nombre de la bdd donde se encuentra el registro "1002568742"?

```
function obtenerBDDconRegistro($bddIterada,$numdoc){
        $SERVIDOR="localhost"; //nombre del servidor
        $USUARIO_BDD="root";   //usuario del servidor
        $CLAVE_BDD="";     //clave del servidor
        $BDD=$bddIterada;  //nombre de la base de datos

        $link = mysql_connect ($SERVIDOR, $USUARIO_BDD, $CLAVE_BDD) or die ("Could not connect"); //establece conexión a la BDD
        mysql_select_db($BDD);  //nombre de la base de datos
        mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `".$BDD.".maefac` WHERE nofact31='".$numdoc."';";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { //Verifica si existe algún registro en la consulta
        }else{
            $BDDconRegistro=$BDD;
        }
        return($BDDconRegistro);   
    }
$listaBDD=array("femar","femarexhimatr","femarexhicent");
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $BDDconRegistro=obtenerBDDconRegistro($listaBDD[$i],"001-002-000421");
}
echo $BDDconRegistro;
```

Comment: Hola, claro que puedes. Pero te pregunto ¿has intentado algo por tu cuenta? Si es así, te invito a compartir el código de lo hayas intentado y explica las dificultades encontradas. Para ello puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: Se me ocurría con un "for" hacer una conexión a cada bdd y capturar la respuesta de aquella que tenga el registro. Sin embargo no tengo idea de cómo obtener el nombre de la bdd cuando la conexión no haga "die" y luego de superar la conexión, al obtener un resultado capturar el nombre de la bdd. Me he pasado 3 horas en el asunto y no encuentro una manera. No es necesario que pongan código, si me dan pistas es bueno. De hecho el ejemplo que puse es lo más simple de lo que realmente deseo hacer. Una vez resuelto el ejemplo propuesto ya me es más fácil codificar lo que deseo hacer.

Comment: Disculpa mi insistencia, pero es poco lo que puedo aportar sin saber siquiera desde dónde planeas realizar la consulta. Veo que hablas de usar un bucle `for`, por lo tanto asumo que harás la consulta usando un script o lenguaje, además, también hablas de hacer una conexión a cada base de datos en cada iteración. De allí asumo que las bases de datos están en servidores separados y por lo tanto cada una requiere un inicio de sesión diferente. Tu desafío está en realizar las consultas y obtener los datos de cada BD para luego procesarlos y decidir de acuerdo al resultado. Corrígeme si me equivoco

Comment: la conexion no tiene por que hacer un die. De hecho, yo omitiria el die ese (que como dice mauricio, no sabemos donde lo planeas poner), y pondria la conexion en un try/catch.

Comment: Sí, el bucle es con php. Efectivamente, las BD no están en servidores diferentes. Y debo aclarar que el detalle del lenguaje se me olvidó citar en el planteamiento del problema. Ahorita lo corrijo. Gracias Mauricio, por tu interés en ayudar.

Comment: He añadido código referente a lo que quiero hacer y que no me ha funcionado. Si tienen alguna sugerencia, quedaré muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he logrado! Esta es la solución. Si pueden mejorarla para aportar, les agradezco mucho.

```
function obtenerBDDconRegistro($bddIterada,$numdoc){
        $SERVIDOR="localhost"; //nombre del servidor
        $USUARIO_BDD="root";   //usuario del servidor
        $CLAVE_BDD="";     //clave del servidor
        $BDD=$bddIterada;  //nombre de la base de datos

        $link = mysql_connect ($SERVIDOR, $USUARIO_BDD, $CLAVE_BDD) or die ("Could not connect"); //establece conexión a la BDD
        mysql_select_db($BDD);  //nombre de la base de datos
        mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `maefac` WHERE nofact31='".$numdoc."';";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) { //Verifica si existe algún registro en la consulta
         return NULL;
        }else{
            $BDDconRegistro=$BDD; 
            return($BDDconRegistro);
        }

    }
$listaBDD=array("femar","femarexhimatr","femarexhicent","femarexhifran","femarexhimach","femarexhiquit","femarmachala","femarparqcalif","femardepocome",
"femartallguay","femartallmach","femarobservac","femarconsigna","femartransito","femarrepuesto","femartopaciomachala","femarexhinavona","femarexhisamb",
"femaroroplaza","femarduranmotos","femarofigye","femarofimachala","femarbom","femarpmbg","femarpexih","femarpproc","femarpdcp","femarprep","femarprepg",
"femarptgye","femarpems","femarpmob","femarprepd");
for($i=0;$i<33;$i++){
    $BDDconRegistro=obtenerBDDconRegistro($listaBDD[$i],$numdoc);
    //echo "#<br>".$BDDconRegistro;
    if($BDDconRegistro!=NULL){
        break;
    }
}
```